# how to access id using variable in jquery

Tags: jquery

html :-

```
<div id="456"></div>
```

JQuery :-

```
var myvar = "456";

$('?----myvar-----?').addClass('newclass');
```

**is it Possible to access "id" without writing $('#123'). i want to use id by using variable**

Comment: Here is simple script `$('#'+myvar).addClass('newclass');`

Comment: FYI, when adding tags, only add the tags that are relevant to the question/issue. This is a pure js/jquery question so I removed the PHP tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple script:

```js
var myvar = '456';
$('#'+myvar).addClass('newclass');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="456">Test Div</div>
```